# Convert array of object by .map issue

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert array of object which is:

```
[
    {
        "url":"link1",
        "id":2,
        "$$hashKey":"object:293"
    },
    {
        "url":"link2",
        "id":2,
        "$$hashKey":"object:300"
    }
]
```

into simple array like this

```
["link1","link2"]
```

Previously i was using `.map` function in order to do that but in this example this code:

```
for(var i = 0, l = $scope.screenshots.rest.length; i < l; i++) {
    photos = photosJson[i].map(function (photo) {
        return photo['url'];
    });
}
```

is giving me error:

> TypeError: photosJson[i].map is not a function

---

I tried to use code from answers but I still have same error so I've done some more debugging:

basically code now is:

```
console.log($scope.screenshots.rest);
console.log('-----');
var photosJson = JSON.stringify($scope.screenshots.rest);
console.log(photosJson);
console.log('-----');
if(photosJson) {
    console.log(photosJson.map(photo => photo.url));
}
```

and the output of this is:

[image: img]

this is weird. Maybe it has something to do with that I'm putting those link into object in array after some async backend call. However I dont think so bacause above code is executed on submit form after user uploaded images and images links are already in object when user submit form.

---

Ok. I found out that I can't use JSON.stringify before `.map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.map` *alone*, not nested inside another `for` loop:

```js
const photos = [
    {
        "url":"link1",
        "id":2,
        "$$hashKey":"object:293"
    },
    {
        "url":"link2",
        "id":2,
        "$$hashKey":"object:300"
    }
];
console.log(
  photos.map(photo => photo.url)
);
```

You might nest `.map` (or some iteration method) inside another iteration method when you have a multidimensional array, but that's not the case here.

Comment: is it photos.map or photosJson?

Comment: Can't be sure, since OP didn't explain what variable name his `array of object` was assigned to, but whichever it was, the `.map(photo => photo.url)` should work fine

Comment: Ok. I found out that I can't use JSON.strigify before `.map`.

Comment: @BT101 Don't `stringify` it first, that turns the array into a string. You can only use array methods like `map` on arrays.

Comment: I was because I have to pass JSON to backend and I thought that `.map` would also work on json

Answer (score 1):

This could happen when the data is empty, just add a null/empty check inside the loop,

```
for(var i = 0, l = $scope.screenshots.rest.length; i < l; i++) {
  if(photosJson && photosJson[i]){
  photos = photosJson[i].map(function (photo) {
        return photo['url'];
    });
  }
}
```

or simply you can do this without loop,

```
photos = photosJson.map(photo => photo.url)
```